# react native callback function in props blocks component to rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this react native component that creates a general numeric input with increase and decrease buttons.

[image: Numeric input with buttons]

```
export default function NumberInput({quantity = 0, onquantityChange}) {
  const [number, SetNumber] = useState(quantity);

  function handleIncrease() {
    SetNumber(number + 1);
    onquantityChange(quantity + 1);
  }


  function handleDecrease() {
    if (number > 0) {
      SetNumber(number - 1);
      onquantityChange(quantity - 1);
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleDecrease} activeOpacity={0.6}>
        <Icon name="minus" size={20} color={colors.white} style={styles.icon} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <AppText style={styles.text}>{number}</AppText>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleIncrease} activeOpacity={0.6}>
        <Icon name="plus" size={20} color={colors.white} style={styles.icon} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

when I press + or - buttons, `onquantityChange` function makes increasing and decreasing of the number to be slow, if I comment it, it will rerender almost in real time. (`onquantityChange` function does some heavy work in parent function).

I also used this version, it is a little better but no significant change:

```
  const [number, SetNumber] = useState(quantity);

  function handleIncrease() {
    SetNumber(number + 1);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    onquantityChange(number);
  }, [number]);

  function handleDecrease() {
    if (number > 0) {
      SetNumber(number - 1);
    }
  }
```

what can I do to make number and UI rerender and does not wait for `onquantityChange`?

Comment: You'll have to move the heavy processing done by `onquantitychange` off the UI thread. I haven't done React Native stuff so I don't know *how* you do that, but if it's doing that much work, it needs to not be in the way of the UI rendering thread. (Or, of course, make it do less work. :-) It's hard to imagine why something called `onquantitychange` would be doing so much work...)

Comment: I used `Pref Monitor` it's not UI thread, JS thread gets slow when I press buttons. It's not so much, I exaggerated a little bit, it changes some context, but we can assume it can do much more, it should not make rerender slowe.

Comment: I assumed the JavaScript thread **was** the UI thread (it is in web development and Electron). The basic observation stands either way: You need to move that processing to a different thread, or reduce the amount of work being done.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: I think another way to get the updated quantity without passing onquantityChange is passing a ref in parent component to child, put it in AppText and listen changes in your parent component

Comment: React reader , every time when any state of a component change, you used `useEffect()` hook and pass `number` as argument, so it also run every time when `number` changed,
So when you want to run expensive `onquantityChange()`?

Comment: @Nur yes, in the second version, 'onquantityChange` runs **after** `number` changes. I wonder why 'number` does not change immediately after I press a button.

Comment: @VoQuocThang: this makes the component to be not so reusable. also it does not change the prformance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `setTimeout` inside the useEffect we can make `onquantityChange` not to run every time `number` changes, also setTimeout runs it "when stack is empty".

> The callbacks you pass to these functions cannot run until the stack on the main thread is empty.

quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals#settimeout)

so I changed my function component to this.

```
//this have to be outside of the function component.
let changeTimeout;

export default function NumberInput({value = 0, onChange}) {
  const [number, SetNumber] = useState(value);

  function handleIncrease() {
    SetNumber(number + 1);
  }

  //use setTimeout to delay onChange to a time when main thread is available 
  useEffect(() => {
    changeTimeout && clearTimeout(changeTimeout);
    changeTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      onChange(number);
    }, 500);
  }, [number]);

  function handleDecrease() {
    if (number > 0) {
      SetNumber(number - 1);
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleDecrease} activeOpacity={0.7}>
        <Icon name="minus" size={20} color={colors.white} style={styles.icon} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <AppText style={styles.text}>{number}</AppText>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleIncrease} activeOpacity={0.7}>
        <Icon name="plus" size={20} color={colors.white} style={styles.icon} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Note that, Main thread still have to do expensive `onChange()` work, So It will freeze other UI, But 500ms later, Also I suggest you to use [v8-android-jit-nointl](https://github.com/Kudo/react-native-v8]) if you care about performance.

Comment: yes, but this way I'll prevent unnecessary running of this expensive task.
thanks for your suggestion, it's interesting.